# Move families of files into their own folders using a text file formatted for the purpose

Tags: powershell

I have archives with filenames like this

```
first_name.part1.rar
first_name.part1.rev
first_name.part2.rar
first_name.part2.rev
second_name.part01.rar
second_name.part01.rev
second_name.part02.rar
second_name.part02.rev
```

In same folder I have a text.txt file formatted in this way

```
Citadel: Forged with Fire;first_name.part1.rar;link
Citadel: Forged with Fire;first_name.part1.rev;link
Citadel: Forged with Fire;first_name.part2.rar;link
Citadel: Forged with Fire;first_name.part2.rev;link

Eurotrack Simulator;second_name.part01.rar;link
Eurotrack Simulator;second_name.part01.rev;link
Eurotrack Simulator;second_name.part02.rar;link
Eurotrack Simulator;second_name.part02.rev;link
```

I try to do this:

**1**. create folders using the first fields from the text file
**2**. move the files of the same families to their respective folders

[image: move]

For example, to extract the year from each line of the txt text file and create the related folders I use this code

```
$movies = @()
(get-content C:\Path\text.txt) | foreach($_){
    $properties = @{
        date = $_.substring($_.IndexOf("(")+1,4)
        name = $_.substring(0,$_.IndexOf("("))
    }
    $movies += New-Object PSObject -Property $properties
}
$movies

foreach($movie in $movies){
    $movie.date
    $datePath = "C:\Path\$($movie.date)"
    if(-not(test-path $datePath)) {
        new-item $datePath -ItemType "directory"
    }
    $words = $movie.name -split '\s'
    $words
    #this is as far as I got
}
```

For example if I want to implement a Regex in powershell script to generate folders and move files in relative folders I can use this

I use a similar script to generate and move files into folders.

```
$ToFolder = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\to"
$FromFolder = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\From"

#Create the sample folder on your desktop
#This line can be commented out if your ToFolder exists
New-Item $ToFolder -ItemType directory -Force

GCI -Path $FromFolder *.torrent | % {
    if ($_.Name -match "(19|20)\d{2}") {

        #Check to see if year folder already exists at the destination
        #If not then create a folder based on this year
        if (!(Test-Path "$ToFolder\$($Matches[0])")) {
            New-Item -Path "$ToFolder\$($Matches[0])" -ItemType directory
        }

        #Transfer the matching file to its new folder
        #Can be changed to Move-Item if happy with the results
        Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "$ToFolder\$($Matches[0])" -Force
    }
}
```

I'm trying to fit and chain the 2 codes but for a different purpose (as shown in the image, not to extract year), but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input file `text.txt` can be treated as a semi-colon (`;`) delimited CSV file, so we can use the `Import-Csv` cmdlet on it to make things a lot easier:

```
$sourcePath = 'D:\Test'
$inputFile  = Join-Path -Path $sourcePath -ChildPath 'text.txt'
# because the title may contain invalid characters for a folder name like ':'
# create a regex to remove those if applicable
$invalid = "[{0}]" -f [RegEx]::Escape(([IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() -join ''))

Import-Csv -Path $inputFile -Delimiter ';' -Header Title,FileName,Link | Group-Object Title | ForEach-Object {
    # combine the Title with the source path. Remove invalid characters from the Title
    $targetFolder = Join-Path -Path $sourcePath -ChildPath ($_.Name -replace $invalid)
    # if the destination folder does not already exist, create it
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $targetFolder -PathType Container)) {
        $null = New-Item -Path $targetFolder -ItemType Directory
    }
    foreach ($fileName in $_.Group.FileName) {
        $targetFile = Join-Path -Path $sourcePath -ChildPath $fileName
        if (Test-Path -Path $targetFile -PathType Leaf) {
            Move-Item -Path $targetFile -Destination $targetFolder -Force
        }
        else {
            Write-Warning "File '$targetFile' not found!"
        }
    }
}
```

**Before:**

```
D:\TEST
    first_name.part1.rar
    first_name.part1.rev
    first_name.part2.rar
    first_name.part2.rev
    second_name.part01.rar
    second_name.part01.rev
    second_name.part02.rar
    second_name.part02.rev
    text.txt
```

**After:**

```
D:\TEST
|   text.txt
|
+---Citadel Forged with Fire
|       first_name.part1.rar
|       first_name.part1.rev
|       first_name.part2.rar
|       first_name.part2.rev
|
\---Eurotrack Simulator
        second_name.part01.rar
        second_name.part01.rev
        second_name.part02.rar
        second_name.part02.rev
```